# Content-Security-Policy error https://ssl.gstatic.com

Tags: cordova, google-chrome-app, onsen-ui, content-security-policy

I am getting an error as captured in the screenshot below:

[image]

It reads:

> Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src file: data: chrome-extension: https://ssl.gstatic.com". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

What am I doing wrong and how can I resolve the *Content-Security-Policy* error?

Below is my meta-tag in, in my index.html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
    content="default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' 
    data: ssl.gstatic.com https://ssl.gstatic.com; 
    style-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 
    chrome-extension: ssl.gstatic.com; 
    script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'self' 
    chrome-extension: file: data: http: https: ssl.gstatic.com
 https://ssl.gstatic.com">
```

I'm using CCA with Onsen UI.

Comment: which platform are you using? WP? have you tried using `ng-csp`?

Comment: Android Platform, how can i use the ngCsp?

Answer (score 5):

Your question is tagged as a Google Chrome App question.

Chrome Apps are [subject to a very specific CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy) **and cannot override it**.

```
default-src 'self';
connect-src *;
style-src 'self' data: chrome-extension-resource: 'unsafe-inline';
img-src 'self' data: chrome-extension-resource:;
frame-src 'self' data: chrome-extension-resource:;
font-src 'self' data: chrome-extension-resource:;
media-src *;
```

> Your Chrome App can only refer to scripts and objects within your app, with the exception of media files (apps can refer to video and audio outside the package). Chrome extensions will let you relax the default Content Security Policy; **Chrome Apps won’t.**

The documentation then proceeds to have a helpful ["How do I.." section](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy#but). Take a look at it and see what fits your needs.

Comment: I changed and still did not work.
It's weird because testing in the browser, it works!
but when it is built into the device, no!

Comment: I said that I changed mine to what you ordered. It is exactly the same. Understood?

Comment: Okay, you need to carefully read the docs. You cannot change it, it's what it always is in Chrome Apps. This probably means you cannot use the library you're using unless you sandbox it.

Comment: I can not use anything outside? for example, a library of Google Maps?

Comment: No, normally not. You can embed web content with `<webview>`, and you can use sandboxing for some tasks. You can of course just fetch data with XHR, but not run outside scripts. _Read the docs I linked!_

Comment: I read, just do not understand why in earlier versions work? As in a mobile app will not be able to make these kinds of requests, did not confused with an extension?

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you just said.

Comment: This type of restriction also applies to a project Cordova app ?

Comment: I don't know, but probably not. It's specific to Chrome Apps and as such also applies to the CCA toolchain.

Comment: I disabled all extensions and google apps and the message is gonne.