# Still getting Content Security Policy(CSP) Errors after putting csp in my manifest.json..?

Tags: google-chrome-app, content-security-policy

I'm trying to create a chrome app which requests access to firebase. I have set my CSP in manifest.json and I'm still getting CSP errors:

```
  "Content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.gstatic.com/ https://*.firebaseio.com https://www.*.googleapis.com; style-src 'self' https://www.googleapis.com/ https://fonts.googleapis.com/; default-src 'self' https://*.firebaseio.com",
```

This is the error I keep getting:

> firebase.js:375 Refused to load the script
>   'https://myapp.firebaseio.com/.lp?start=t&ser=30696138&cb=1&v=5'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "default-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:".
>   Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is
>   used as a fallback.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Content-Security-Policy error https://ssl.gstatic.com](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31149395/content-security-policy-error-https-ssl-gstatic-com)

Comment: Short version: `content_security_policy` mainfest key is ignored for Chrome Apps.

Comment: Well that sucks. :/

Comment: Chrome Apps are being deprecated anyway. You should consider another platform such as NW.js or Electron